# assign ngStyle according to a condition

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to change the `background-color` of a **li** according to the score of the vote: heigh or low

```
<div *ngIf="upvote > downvote" [ngStyle]="{background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3);}" >
```

Comment: ngStyle should be inside the div, not outside it, unless you forgot to post something. Other than that, you can use a ternary operator directly in the background-color. Why would you do that anyway?  the ngIf will hide the element if it's falsy.

Comment: @briosheje it is inside the div ! it closes at the end of the line

Comment: @julia [ngStyle] works upon tags, this won't work in this way.

Comment: @briosheje what should I have done ?

Comment: @julia  try this <div *ngIf="upvote > downvote" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':check=== 'upvote ' ? hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3) : hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3) }"></div>

Comment: @julia what is the expected goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected use below option of checking condition inside ngStyle and issue from your code is that div will be not available when downvote > upvote due to ngIf

Other minor observations
1. Use quotes around background-color and color
2. Remove ngIf to handle both conditions (upvote > downvote , downvote > upvote) and move condition inside ngStyle

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': upvote > downvote? 'red': 'blue'}" >
Test
  </div>
```

Code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssy7uo?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Note:** Use `ngClass` to handle more CSS properties to avoid handling too many entries with `ngStyle`

Comment: how to write elseif using this syntax ?? exp if upvote > downvote  color = blue ; elseif upvote < downvote color = red else do nothing

Comment: @julia, use another ternary to check upvote < downvote and set color , [ngStyle]="{'background-color': upvote > downvote? 'red': (upvote < downvote? 'blue': 'white')}"   .....Hope it works :)

Comment: do u have any explanation why my code didn't work at first? it is logically correct

Comment: No , ngif will remove div when upvote <downvote in your code

Comment: I just didn't understand why would ngif remove the div (I'm new to angular I do not master it well)

Comment: Div will displayed if ngif is true I.e upvote > downvote from your code... when upvote < downvote as ngif condition is false, so div will be not displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196602/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-julia).

Answer (score 1):

you should probably create 2 classes, one for each style. Then you can use ngClass. Example below where you have 2 classes named red or blue. The condition is made up. you can put whatever you want there

```
 <div [ngClass]="{'blue': vote == 'high', 'red': vote == 'low'}"></div>
```

Comment: it is not possible with ngStyle ?

Comment: [ngClass] seems more dependable for reacting to changing values, instead of just on initial load. That's just my personal findings. Also it's better practice to uses classes for everything, and not inline styles

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case this code is work.

```
<div *ngIf="upvote > downvote" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':check=== 'upvote ' ? hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3) : hsla(100, 20%, 40%, 0.5) }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change background colour on `upvote` is greater than `downvote` you can do it as follows.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ background-color: (upvote > downvote) ? hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.3) : white }" >
```